# Perform $.getJSON without using JQuery

Tags: javascript

How do I get country code using javascript only, I am not allowed to use jQuery.

I have seen some sites like http://ipinfo.io , but all examples uses JQuery getJson, can I implement the same method :

```
var country_code = null;
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/' + userip, function(data){
    country_code = data.country;
    alert(country_code);
});
```

I tried the following, but it returns a page instead:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onload = function(elements) { console.log(elements); };
request.open("get", "http://ipinfo.io", true);
request.send();
```

Comment: Can you use `fetch` or do you have to use XHR?

Comment: have you even googled this?

Comment: fetch is not supported in IE

Comment: @cruiser , it is been an hour googling it

Comment: ajax pure javascript google search returns plenty of answers

Comment: See http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json. They have alternatives to JQuery methods written in pure javascript.

Comment: Do you want to get country code of a current country?

Or you want to get country code knowing the country name?

Comment: @MaciejCaputa , I want a country_code of the visitor.

Answer (score 2):

Working example:

```js
var someIp = '8.8.8.8';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
      alert('There was an error 400');
    }
    else {
      alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
    }
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "//ipinfo.io/"+someIp+"/json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  pending
</div>
```

The **ipinfo.io** service returns JSON format only when proper header requesting JSON is attached. But it can be specified easily also with the `/json` directly in the requesting url.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that I missed to append the IP , check the question. Thanks a lot :)